# How can I send ALL cron output to syslog rather than email

Tags: cron, syslog

I am running cron with `-m off` to stop it sending email and then the `-s` option is supposed to send all output to syslog.

Cron cmdline is

```
crond -s -m off
```

My cron  job for testing this is

```
* * * * * root /bin/echo hello
```

What I see in `/var/log/cron` is

```
Jun 17 17:06:01 www08 CROND[4165]: h<FF>
```

Basically all I get is the first character `h` and then `<FF>`

If I change the cron job to be

```
* * * * * root /bin/echo world
```

Then I get the first character `w` and then `<FF>`

Ultimately, what I am after is a way of getting all output from cronjobs logged to syslog so that I can manage them with our log alerting system.

I dont want to modify all the cron jobs as some are put there automatically from rpm packages and others by different departments. I am after a solution that sorts this issue once and for all rather than constantly appending `2>&1 | logger -t myscriptname` to the end of every cron job on 100 machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix has been back-ported now, and is available for CentOS 6 - https://pkgs.org/centos-6/centos-updates-x86_64/cronie-1.4.4-16.el6_8.2.x86_64.rpm.html .  Well done Tim for reporting it to Red Hat!

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The version that is in centos 6 has a bug that was fixed 4 years ago but hasn't been backported by Redhat.

https://www.fedorahosted.org/cronie/ticket/8

Going to build my own revision.

Answer (score 1):

can you run crond with -x for debugging and see if it helps?  I've tried running the same job with same crond option and it works fine for me. I'm using Centos7. Also have you tried using "hello".

Comment: btw, why you using "root" in your command line?  It will think of it as a command and try to execute "root" failing with err..

Comment: system crontabs, i.e. the ones similar in `/etc/crontab` `/etc/cond[.daily|.weekly|.monthly|.d/*]` do need a username.